# Array advanced search by two parameters

Tags: php, arrays, search, advanced-search

I saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217746/how-to-sort-an-array-by-similarity-in-relation-to-an-inputted-word) And I have used this code:

```
$arr = array("hello", "try", "hel", "hey hello");
$search = "hey"; //your search var

for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
   $temp_arr[$i] = levenshtein($search, $arr[$i]);
}
asort($temp_arr);
foreach ($temp_arr as $k => $v) {
    $sorted_arr[] = $arr[$k];
}
```

But now I want to search by array in array. For example, if I have this array:

```
$test = array(
    0 => array("google", "http://www.google.com"),
    1 => array("test", "http://www.test.com"),
    2 => array("test2", "http://www.test2.com")
)
```

So I want resort by `$test[$x][0]` ( `$x = num` ), How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).
Example:

```
    uasort($test, function($a, $b){
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    });
```

If you php version < 5.3, you need to define the cmp function.

Comment: It's looks very difficult, Could you help me with that function?

Comment: @Daniel Edited. Please check.

Comment: I unsuccess to understand how is going to work with my code that i posted at the first post. :S

Comment: It resorts your $test array. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to sort by: $arr = array("hello", "try", "hel", "hey hello");
$search = "hey"; //your search var

for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
   $temp_arr[$i] = levenshtein($search, $arr[$i]);
}
asort($temp_arr);
foreach($temp_arr as $k => $v) {
    $sorted_arr[] = $arr[$k];
}

Comment: @Daniel You means you want to use `levenshtein` to cmpare? So what you need to do is replace the cmp function `strcmp` with your own compare logic.

Comment: What does `levenshtein` returns ? int?

Comment: "This function returns the Levenshtein-Distance between the two argument strings or -1, if one of the argument strings is longer than the limit of 255 characters. " I don't really know what it means.

Comment: So if you don't know what it means, why do you want to use it in your code .

Comment: I know that it sort my array like I want to :) its enough for me ^^