# sort php array by relevance

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a php array in a way that it compares to a certain string and

1. Exact match of the string is in the top
2. the rest need to be sorted according to relevance to the string. The most similar string to be next and so on.

**I am getting the array remotely so i do not have any control over sql statements**
I have googled and couldn't find a satisfying answer.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked the PHP Manual for different array sorting functions?

Comment: provide an example. & refer this : http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7217746/2603230

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `usort` with a callback function that utilizes [levenshtein()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) to sort your array.

Comment: THank you i will try the solutions